# Bootstrap hide element puts content on new line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap to conditionally display content only on larger devices. It works, but there is an issue:

```
<a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""><span class="d-none d-md-block">My strapline<span></a>
```

The problem - the span content now aligns under the logo, rather than next to it without the "d-none d-md-block" class attributes.

How do I get the span content to stay inline with the logo?

Thank you

Comment: `d-md-block` change span to `display;block;`, you can try `d-md-inline` instead, span default display is `inline`